# How to inspect the content of non-generic TObjectList when debugging?

Tags: delphi, debugging, generics, inspector, tobjectlist

**Summarization:**
1. Manual typecast when debugging, as LachlanG and Ken pointed out.
2. Make use of the concept of Debugger Visualizers introduced since Delphi 2010.
3. Switch to generics counterparts.

=========================================

Take the following code for example:

If breakpoints are set at the end of `TestRegular`, and at the end of `TestGenerics`, respectively, one can see the items of the generic list(and even the content of the items) through the debug inspector, but nothing meaningful (not even the count) for the regular tobjectlist, when one hovers the mouse on the `tmp` variable. I am wondering if there is some way to achieve similar debug-time functionality for regular tobjectlist?

```
    unit Unit2;

    interface

    uses
      Contnrs, Generics.Collections,
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs;

    type
      TMyItem = class;
      TMyItemList = class;
      TForm2 = class;

      TMyItem = class
      private
        fname: string;
      public
        property name: string read fname;
        constructor Create(aName: string);
      end;

      TMyItemList = class(TObjectList)
      protected
        procedure SetObject (Index: Integer; Item: TMyItem);
        function GetObject (Index: Integer): TMyItem;
      public
        function Add (Obj: TMyItem): Integer;
        procedure Insert (Index: Integer; Obj: TMyItem);
        property Objects [Index: Integer]: TMyItem
          read GetObject write SetObject; default;
      end;

      TForm2 = class(TForm)
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
        procedure TestRegular;
        procedure TestGenerics;
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form2: TForm2;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    { TMyItem }

    constructor TMyItem.Create(aName: string);
    begin
      fname := aName;
    end;

    { TMyItemList }

    function TMyItemList.Add(Obj: TMyItem): Integer;
    begin
      Result := inherited Add (Obj);
    end;

    procedure TMyItemList.SetObject(Index: Integer; Item: TMyItem);
    begin
      inherited SetItem (Index, Item);
    end;

    function TMyItemList.GetObject(Index: Integer): TMyItem;
    begin
      Result := inherited GetItem (Index) as TMyItem;
    end;

    procedure TMyItemList.Insert(Index: Integer; Obj: TMyItem);
    begin
      inherited Insert(Index, Obj);
    end;

    {TForm2}

    procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      TestGenerics;
      TestRegular;
    end;

    procedure TForm2.TestRegular;
    var
     tmp: TMyItemList;
    begin
     tmp := TMyItemList.Create;
     tmp.Add(TMyItem.Create('1'));
     tmp.Add(TMyItem.Create('2'));
     tmp.Free;
    end;

    procedure TForm2.TestGenerics;
    var
     tmp: TObjectList<TMyItem>;
    begin
     tmp := TObjectList<TMyItem>.Create;
     tmp.Add(TMyItem.Create('1'));
     tmp.Add(TMyItem.Create('2'));
     tmp.Free;
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: it ought to be possible to write a debugger helper or whatever it's called that would query the object dynamically for its class and then go to work. I'd just stop using the untyped version though. In fact I already have!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Could you help to mention an example of debugger helper?

Comment: By `In fact I already have!`, do you mean that you have switched to generics collections? Could you share your opinion about the performance?

Comment: performance of generic version better because there is no dynamic cast.

Comment: It's a [Debugger Visualizer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Debugger_Visualizers) in fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to improve what appear in the mouse cursor hover hint.

You can however use typecasts inside Debug windows just as you can within source code.

For example you could typecast the tmp variable to TObjectList(tmp) from within the Evaluation Window (Ctrl F7) or create a Watch (Ctrl F5) on the typecasted variable.

Comment: !LachlanG: Thank you very much for your comment! You are right! Write `TObjectList(tmp)` within the evaluation window, switch to the properties tab, and I can get the count. Could you help to mention whether I can also inspect the items in the regular TObjectList?

Comment: @Xichen Li - Just change your typecast in the Evaluate Window to `TMyItemList(tmp)`, and you should be able to reference the individual items as `TMyItemList(tmp)[0].Name` and `TMyItemList(tmp)[1].Name`. If this doesn't work, typecast a little more: `TMyItem(TMyItemList(tmp).[0].Name`.

Comment: @Ken: Thank you very much for your suggestion! It works great using `TMyItemList(tmp)[0].Name`!

Answer (score 1):

There are [Debugger Visualizers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Debugger_Visualizers) that allow you to customise the debugger's visualization capabilities. I've never used them, but it is my understanding that you could combine them with some RTTI and give richer information about a `TObject` instance.

However, using generics is what you want here. It gives compile time typing which has manifest advantages. I'd simply do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions very much!

Comment: I tried to learn Open Tools API to create customrized Debugger Visualizers. But it looks I have to create it for every singlet TObjectList descendant. As you say, generics is probably the best choice.

Comment: I'm sure it could be done once for TObjectList and let RTTI do the heavy lifting. But generics win!

Comment: Thanks for your mentioning that it can be done! I then should try it some time later.